# Mini Cart item count give wrong value in Magento1

Tags: mini-cart, magento1.9.2.4, cart-items

I am using Magento1.9.2.4.
I remove the minicart from header and insert it in customer footer phtml file, As the work of remove and insert has been done by XML.

Mini cart is working fine, the only issue is that Count on mini cart are wrong, If I disable BlockHTML cache the counts are showing accurate.

I am using Porto theme, I did the below:
my theme's layout local.xml:

```
<default>
        <reference name="header">
          <action method="unsetChild"><name>minicart</name></action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="footer">
          <action method="insert"><block>minicart</block></action>
          <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/custom_footer.phtml</template></action>
       </reference>
</default>
```

My custom_footer.phtml file:

```
<li id="cart_custom" class="list-top cart cart_custom"> 
<a href="<?php echo $cart; ?>">
    <div class="cart-area">
        <?php 
        echo $this->getChildHtml('minicart'); //MiniCart
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo "<img src='".Mage::getBaseUrl('media').trim("icon_cart").".png'/>"; ?>
    <span><?php echo $this->__('Cart') ?></span>
</a>
</li>
```

Suggest how can I fix it.

Comment: Could you please provide a code that you did so I can have review

Comment: @sagarumaretiya, Please check, I update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your local.xml code with little modification in my local machine with magento 1.9.3.4 and get it working. Please try 
following code

```
<default>
        <reference name="header">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>minicart_head</name></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="footer">
            <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_lifetime</key></action>
            <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_tags</key></action>
            <action method="insert"><block>minicart_head</block></action>
        </reference>
</default>
```

Let me know if you are still having a issue

Comment: its not working, still have the same issue

Comment: Are you using any third party cache or native Magento cache system ?

Comment: Could you please also make sure that your store have any file  named with turpentine_esi.xml ?

Comment: Yes, No such File or any extension has been used. Even If I try the same with default magento, It is having the same issue.

Comment: You can try with  <flush_events> in your local.xml.

Comment: Can you please share any link, So I can follow that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71163/discussion-between-sagar-umaretiya-and-yogita).

Answer (score 0):

Update your `custom_footer.phtml` as follows.

```
<li id="cart_custom" class="list-top cart cart_custom"> <a href="<?php echo $cart; ?>">
<div class="cart-area">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('minicart', false); //MiniCart ?>
</div>
<?php echo "<img src='".Mage::getBaseUrl('media').trim("icon_cart").".png'/>"; ?>
<span><?php echo $this->__('Cart') ?></span></a>
</li>
```

Clear the cache and refresh.